# Python arrays dimension issues

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am struggling once again with Python, `NumPy` and arrays to compute some calculations between matrices.

The code part that is likely not working properly is as follows:

```
train, test, cv = np.array_split(data, 3, axis = 0) 
train_inputs = train[:,: -1]
test_inputs = test[:,: -1]
cv_inputs = cv[:,: -1]

train_outputs = train[:, -1]
test_outputs = test[:, -1]
cv_outputs = cv[:, -1]
```

When printing those matrices informations (`np.ndim`, `np.shape` and `dtype` respectively), this is what you get:

```
2
1
2
1
2
1
(94936, 30)
(94936,)
(94936, 30)
(94936,)
(94935, 30)
(94935,)
float64
float64
float64
float64
float64
float64
```

I believe it is missing 1 dimension in all `*_output` arrays.

The other matrix I need is created by this command:

```
newMatrix = neuronLayer(30, 94936)
```

In which `neuronLayer` is a class defined as:

```
class neuronLayer():
    def __init__(self, neurons, neuron_inputs):
        self.weights = 2 * np.random.random((neuron_inputs, neurons)) - 1
```

Here's the final output:

```
outputLayer1 = self.__sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.layer1.weights))
ValueError: shapes (94936,30) and (94936,30) not aligned: 30 (dim 1) != 94936 (dim 0)
```

Python is clearly telling me the matrices are not adding up but I am not understanding where is the problem.

Any tips?

PS: The full code is pasted [ħere](http://pastebin.com/vkDf41sQ).

Comment: When using `dot(x, y)` (on 2d arrays), numpy requires that the shapes of `x` and `y` respectively are `(A, B)` and `(B,C)`, whereas yours are `(A, B)` and `(A, B)`

Comment: As mentioned below, trying that will bring a `Memory Error`. Not sure if that is related with my old computer or so but initially thought it just wasn't a proper fix.

Comment: What is the `dot` supposed to produce?  A 30x30 or a 94936x94936 (too big?) array?

Comment: The `np.dot()` function is used to multiply matrices, isn't it? The idea is to multiply the input matrix and the weights, which are 94936x30 and 94936x1, respectively. That should produce a 949346x1, right? The code might be wrong for that purpose

Comment: Review how you generate the `weights`

Comment: It is easy to add a dimension to `outputs` with `train[:, [-1]]` or `train[:,-1][:,None]`

Comment: _"94936x30 and 94936x1, respectively. That should produce a 949346x1"_ - no, that's not how matrix multiplication works. You should read up on matrix algebra with non-square matrices

Comment: The parts of your code like `train_inputs.np.transpose.np.dot` make no sense

Comment: Usually when people ask questions like this they are using a package like `scikit_learn`.  Packages like that should be clear about what they expect in terms of array dimensions.  For example, does a single feature `y` have to be (N,) or (N,1)?  If you've written your own neuralnet code (or adapted someone elses) make sure you understand the array shapes are every step.  Be extra careful if adapting MATLAB code.

Comment: I've written my own neural network code with the help of the internet, yes. As for the way weights are generated, it might be the only part I haven't reviewed and it might be worthy to check it out.
@Eric, if not like that, Python brings AttributeErrors. I am not an expert anyways, so if doesn't make sense, I'd appreciate if you could bring any tips to solve the issue if that's okay.

Thanks both for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layer1 = neuronLayer(30, 94936)    # 29 neurons with 227908 inputs
layer2 = neuronLayer(1, 30)         # 1 Neuron with the previous 29 inputs
```

where `nueronLayer creates

```
self.weights = 2 * np.random.random((neuron_inputs, neurons)) - 1
```

the 2 weights are (94936,30) and (30,1) in size.

This line does not make any sense.  I surprised it doesn't give an error

```
layer1error = layer2delta.dot(self.layer2.weights.np.transpose)
```

I suspect you want `np.transpose(self.layer2.weights)` or `self.layer2.weights.T`.

But maybe it doesn't get there.  `train` first calls `think` with a (94936,30) `inputs`

```
    outputLayer1 = self.__sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.layer1.weights))
    outputLayer2 = self.__sigmoid(np.dot(outputLayer1, self.layer2.weights))
```

So it tries to do a `np.dot` with 2 (94936,30), (94936,30) arrays.  They aren't compatible for a dot.  You could transpose one or the other, producing either (94936,94936) array or (30,30).  One looks too big.  The (30,30) is compatible with the weights for the 2nd layer.

```
np.dot(inputs.T, self.layer1.weights)
```

has a chance of working right.

```
np.dot(outputLayer1, self.layer2.weights)
(30,30) with (30,1) => (30,1)
```

But then you do

```
train_outputs - outputLayer2
```

That will have problems regardless of whether `train_outputs` is (94936,) or (94936,1)

You need to make sure that arrays shapes flow correctly through the calculation.  Don't just check them at the start.  Check then internally.  And make you sure you understand what shapes they should have at each step.

It would be a whole lot easier to develop and test this code with much smaller inputs and layers, something like 10 samples and 3 features.  That way you can look at the values as well as the shapes.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I learned a lot with this.
I knew for a start the matrices sizes and dimensions weren't correct, just couldn't figure where. Although, you mentioned a good alternative to start working with this and that is to start with something smaller and then scale it higher. This might work to understand well the code and what it is doing. As for the line it doesn't make sense, it doesn't either to me :) I need to multiply a transposed matrix. Just couldn't figure out the right order to do so. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

np.dot uses matrix multiplication when its arguments are matrices. It looks like your code is trying to multiply two non-square matrices together with the same dimensions which doesn't work. Perhaps you meant to transpose one of the matrices? Numpy matrices have a T property that returns the transpose, you could try:

```
self.__sigmoid(np.dot(inputs.T, self.layer1.weights))
```

Comment: That outputs `Memorry Error`. This computer is old though, so that could be an issue. I have tried that but since I got this error, I though this wasn't a fix.

Comment: @GustavoSilva: What shape do you want `np.dot(...)` to be here? I think this is making it `(94936, 94936)`, which is obviously pretty big